# Apache mod_deflate based on url parameters

Tags: apache, mod-deflate

Can mod_deflate module in apache be invoked based on url parameters and not for all the server requests

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, `?foo=bar` in your URL? Maybe you could specify what you're trying to do exactly, besides the URL parameters etc. -- a little use case. In general, `mod_deflate` can be configured with `<Directory />` and `<Location />` in Apache.

More details here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html

I'll be happy to extend my answer, when you provide more background.

**UPDATE:** Use a rewrite rule to make `?foo=bar` turn into `/foo/bar` (or similar -- whatever works in your app). Then use `<Location />` to match and enable `mod_deflate`. I don't think that's very feasible though.

Usually, I'd advice something else, if you expanded your question as of why you are doing this and what you think the gain is.

Comment: Yes. You got it right. Can I have based on url parameters like foo=bar